# Is it ever grammatically correct to say "And you, my."

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, coordinating-conjunctions

If it is acceptable to answer

> I love you.

with

> And I you.

which we could represent as:

> And I <s>love</s> you.

Would it be acceptable to answer:

> You're my hero.

with

> And you my.

in other words:

> And you <s>are</s> my <s>hero</s>.

1. Why is the gap allowed in the first response?
2. Does this allow for gaps in the second response too?
3. If not, why not? (in relation to each gap)

Comment: Would you say, “And you are my.” Or “And you are mine.”?

Comment: @Jim Well, yes, but you wouldn't normally say "I you" instead of "I love you". So the fact that you know that we normally say "mine" when there isn't a following noun isn't as pertinent here. And you've left the equivalent verb **in** your sentence, which kind of misses the whole point of the question!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - I left the verb in so you could see where the end result comes from- by eliding the verb.

Comment: @Jim But why is it the just verb that's elided? (Fwiw, it isn't always). And why's the verb elideable in the first place? And if it is, why isn't *hero* too? (*mine* replaces *my hero*, it doesn't account for an elision of *hero*, if you see what I mean)

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't see anything wrong with the following: **A**:  "I love you." **B**: "And I you."

Comment: @Robusto No, quite! But why?  (Jim's version is **A**: "You are my hero." **B**: "And you are mine" instead of **A**: "You are my hero." **B**: "And you mine", which would be a proper comparitor - it doesn't seem quite as good as OP's, but ...). Note that this seems unfeasible **A**: "I love you". **B** "I you".

Comment: Come on Prof Lawler! One for you!

Comment: It is ploddingly dull to echo “I love you” with “And I love you”. “And I you” is concise, and by omitting the word “love” emphasises it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do this is that "my" is actually a personal possessive determiner. You can replace "my hero" with the personal possessive pronoun "mine" though.

You are my hero.

And you mine.

Comment: Technically it is a personal possessive determiner, not an adjective. These occupy the same syntactic slot in a noun phrase that articles and demonstratives use, and so personal determiners necessarily block articles and demonstratives from appearing alongside them. Adjectives go to the right of all determiner slots, and in a prescribed order. *My other red riding hood has a tear in it.* In contrast a pronoun like *mine* is all you need in the noun phrase: *Mine lost its feather.*

Comment: "Adjectives go to the right of all determiner slots" Provided that you then treat "such a", "quite a" and "What a ...!" as a two-word Det rather than as Adj Det.